# My datepicker wont change its value in react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-hooks

Im using react hooks to change the datepicker value, but it wont change, it work normally in class component, but i want to change it to hooks component

Code below doesnt work

```
function Example() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState({
    startDate: new Date(),
    endDate: new Date(),
    key: 'selection',
  });

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setValue((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    }));
  };

  return (
         <InputDate
            name="value"
            max={30}
            value={value}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
  );
}
```

Code below is work(Class Component)

```
class Example extends Component {
  state = {
    value: {
      startDate: new Date(),
      endDate: new Date(),
      key: 'selection',
    }
  }

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
            <InputDate
              name="value"
              max={30}
              value={this.state.value}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to event pooling. You need to extract values from the event in the handler itself.

**UPD.** I assume the rest of the code if correct: names, `InputDate` handles the shape of the value you are feeding to it, etc.

```
function Example() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState({
    startDate: new Date(),
    endDate: new Date(),
    key: 'selection',
  });

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const {name, value} = e.target;

    setValue((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [name]: value,
    }));
  };

  return (
         <InputDate
            name="value"
            max={30}
            value={value}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 function Example() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState({
    startDate: new Date(),
    endDate: new Date(),
    key: 'selection',
  });

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setValue((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [e.target.name]: new Date(e.target.value),
    }));
  };

  return (
         <InputDate
            name="value"
            max={30}
            value={value}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
  );
}
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation to your code - it is very hard to understand something when it isn't explained.